# Is there a way to get all instructions my CPU supports programmatically?

Tags: assembly, cpu, machine-code

Or is there a tool for this kind of job?

I want also get the corresponding machine code for each instruction.

Comment: Yes. What CPU are you looking for specifically?

Comment: So what are you trying to do then? Software (or it's vm) is compiled for a certain architecture.

Comment: Oops,my CPU is Intel Pentium,where can I find instructions/machine code it supports?

Comment: Ignoring all the x86-centric answers below, in the general case, you'd need to empirically determine all available instructions based on observed behavior. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 5):

The CPUID instruction reports what functionality the CPU supports for x86 processors.

http://www.intel.com/assets/pdf/appnote/241618.pdf

You'll have to refer to the Instruction Reference Manuals for the opcodes, there's no way the CPU can tell you that 'opcode 0x?? is the XYZ instruction' programatically.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is information on the instruction set. For Intel processesors, you can look here: http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/.

For x86-64 and Itanium, refer to chapter 3 in this PDF: http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/325383.pdf

Every architecture I've cared enough to learn that deeply has a similar manual.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine not, as that is something that the CPU would have to support. Google your processor.

Comment: I guess there's some way the CPU tells the OS which instructions it supports,and that's by programe.

Comment: No, I think the OS is coded in a way that it knows all the instructions beforehand (more like it was compiled correctly, and it can send off the appropriate instructions). If it was possible, then compilers would not need to know anything about the processor to compile. they could just ask the OS  for the istruction set.

Answer (score 0):

CPU-Z is a freeware program that will return the Instructions supported.

To get this information by code I would imagine you would need deep knowledge of ASM Assembly.